# REGEX_REPLACE not working as expected in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, regex, oracle10g

I am using `REGEX_REPLACE` method in the Oracle 10g but it is not replacing the strings.

Here is what I'm (unsuccessfully) trying:

```
Select REGEX_REPLACE('Mathew, Sajan K ext (E IT S US 1)','\\([^\\)]+\\)','') "REGEXP_REPLACE"
```

Comment: What are you trying to replace? It does not look like a valid regex.

Comment: I used this regex in the c# code. I want replace the text inside brackets to empty.It works fine in c#. I cant figure out is it valid in the oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select REGEX_REPLACE('Mathew, Sajan K ext (E IT S US 1)','\([^\)]+\)','') "REGEXP_REPLACE"
```

Notice that I just removed the extra escape characters `\`, some languages seem to require you to double escape, some don't.

Ref: [Oracle SQL Database Reference REGEX_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)